# Вопрос о регистрации BroadcastReceiver в Android

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

Меня интересуют следующие вопросы, я только изучаю Android разработку и принятое направление может быть в корне неверным, прошу поправить если что не так:

1) Можно ли как то узнать информацию о всех зарегистрированных в моем приложении BroadcastReceiver.

2) Я регистрирую `registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter)`, но не вызываю потом `unregisterReceiver(receiver)` и закрываю приложение (принудительно, не сворачиваю), а после открываю приложение и опять срабатывает `registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter)`. Все работает как надо, в логи приходит только одно сообщение `onReceive` от последнего зарегистрированного BroadcastReceiver.

Меня интересует вопрос: что происходит с первым BroadcastReceiver после закрытия приложения. Остается ли он в системе? Остается ли зарегистрированным? И не будут ли копиться эти объект при регулярном закрытии/открытии приложения?

P.S. Нет возможности вызывать **unregisterReceiver**, так как регистрирую *"вещатель"* в `App extends Application` и у него нет методов `onPause`, `onDestroy` и т.д.

Т.е. *"вещатель"* нужен во время работы всего приложения, а не какой-то конкретной **Activity**. Что бы не создавать и не регистрировать *"все это дело"* в каждой **Activity** решил вынести в `App extends Application`.

Comment: Используйте программно, или через manifest?

Comment: @danilshik создаю программно.... Даже не знал, что можно регистрировать через manifest. Верно ли я понял, при регистрации через manifest я могу не заморачиваться с отменой регистрации вещателя, т.е. пока приложение работает, даже в фоне (свернуто и по нему не прошелся сборщик мусора) вещатель у меня будет работать?

Comment: Через manifest работает BroadcastReviewer, который даже если приложение полностью закрыто, он живет в системе